# Getting iOS version before enrollment (Without Agent)

Tags: iphone, ios, mdm

How to conditionally set the

```
<key>AccessRights</key>
<integer>$enrollment_code</integer>
```

in MDM enrollment profile based on iOS version its getting installed..

like 5.0 and above it must be 8191
and below 5.0 it needs to be 2047

**In the Phase1: profile service, we do not get the iOS version.. 
So where to get the iOS version before enrollment.**

PS: I am enrolling devices without agent (So agent cannot be an option to send it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the User-Agent reported from the browser.